# Add annotation to legend colourbar in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to add an annotation to a colourbar/legend in ggplot.  Is this possible?  Example MWE below with a picture of what I'm basically trying to achieve - adding a few lines or boxes and some labels to the colour bar legend.  The annotations are to indicate critical points in time in the system being plotted (which I calculate separately).  They will either be lines or boxes, I need to try to see what actually works.

```
library(tidyverse)
x <- runif(20)
y <- runif(20)
t <- runif(20)

df <- data.frame(t,x,y)
df<- df[order(t),]

ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_path(size = 0.2, aes(colour = t))
```

[image: example of desired appearance]

The real data is a bunch of lines and annotations refer to summary data, so not practical to show on the x-y plot.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the breaks of the legend and then change the labels:

```
scale_fill_continuous(breaks = c(0.25,a,0.5,b,0.75), labels = c('0.25','a','0.5','b','0.75'))
```

With `a` and `b` the value you want to have the breaks.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  I don't want to change the breaks in the colourbar (or add some extras), I want to add an annotation over the top of the legend.  It will be either a line or a box, coloured differently to the legend, and with text next to it.

Comment: You could try to increase the plot margin (`theme(plot.margin = unit(c(1, 5, 1, 1))` with the margin you want) and then use `annotate()` to add the elements you want, with coordinates outside the plot (ie `annotate("text", x = 5, y = 0.8, label = "a")`)

Comment: Thanks I'll give that a try